# How to avoid page views from an adult site in my blog?

Tags: blog, backlinks, blogger, adult-content, page-views

In my blogspot i found huge page views from an adult site. But i checked my websites backlink and that particular porn site is not in that list. I don't know how those page views comes and how to avoid those links. Please give suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably "referrer SPAM". These people drive traffic to their own website by making fake website requests with their website as referrer. If possible try to ignore them.

Does this solve your question?

Comment: How to ignore those spammers?

Comment: Your answer is correct but can you give me some ideas to ignore those spam visits? is it possible?

Comment: If you host a blog yourself, you could try to block the specific IP address, or remove certain referrers from your stats with a script. But if it's not hosted by yourself, then there's not much you can do...

Comment: Its my own blog. what's the script for remove certain referrers?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a script, but you could google something like "block referrer spam".

Comment: @JohnSanjay, if I want to block a particular IP address, I usually use a service like Cloudflare